# React Native old data state gotcha

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There is a "gotcha" in react native (react?) where if you update state with the data from previous state, it does not recognize the state change, and does not rerender. Can someone remind me the work around for this to get state to rerender when its received the updated data?

example code: should rerender state, but doesnt because state doesnt recognize a change

```
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const addImage = async (data) => {
    let oldImages = images;

    oldImages.push({
      url: data,
      order: images.length + 1,
    });
    setImages(oldImages);
  };
```

Comment: Thats not the gotcha. The gotcha is that you dont push because it mutates state. You need to copy the array and use an entirely new array reference. `let oldImages = images` is still mutating the original array.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

When you do this:

```
let oldImages = images;
```

you're assigning a reference of `images` to `oldImages`. Under the hood React essentially does a strict equality comparison (`===`) to determine whether to rerender (very simplified explanation, see [reference](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d1f51f34535d00b5985744b0acb45c7f35ab90c6/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.old.js#L1995) for context). As `oldImages` is a reference to `images` (the current state) the result of the comparison would yield that they are equal to each other. As a result React will not rerender.

## Solution

Create a new array so the references are not equal:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

const addImage = async (data) => {
  setImages([
    ...images,
    {
      url: data,
      order: images.length + 1,
    },
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround i was looking for, you only need to wrap the old data in array brackets with ellipses

```
 const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const addImage = async (data) => {
    let oldImages = [...images];

    oldImages.push({
      url: data,
      order: images.length + 1,
    });
    setImages(oldImages);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answer have explained what to do to fix your problem, i will provide an example to show you what mutation did to your code and how to fix it from vanilla JS

```js
const vehicles = ['bus', 'car'];

const oldVehicles = vehicles;

oldVehicles.push('van');

console.log(vehicles)
console.log(oldVehicles)
```

From the example given above, you can see that we only pushed `van` into `oldVehicles` but when we print `vehicles`, clearly we can see that `van` is in `vehicles` too. This is what we mean by array is shared by reference when you done `const oldVehicles = vehicles`

To fix the above code sample, what you will need is to create a new reference instead of sharing reference as shown below

```js
const vehicles = ['bus', 'car'];

const oldVehicles = [...vehicles]; // <== here

oldVehicles.push('van');

console.log(vehicles)
console.log(oldVehicles)
```